# with redux-form and react-select.creatable why does a blur event clear the input?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, redux-form, react-select

i'm using:

- react 15.6.2
- redux-form 7.2.0
- react-select 1.2.1

i don't have a codepen set up for this yet, it's complicated. hoping someone will see the problem from the source alone.  i can dream, can't i?

i have a `redux-form` displaying a `invoice` object:

```
invoice = { client: { email: 'someguy@somewhere.com' } }
```

summary: i'm using `react-select.creatable` as an autocomplete component for an email dropdown.  selecting an `email` sets the `client` on the `invoice`.

[image: typing and hitting enter creates and selects the new option]

when i create a new email address and select it, then blur out of the input field, the input value gets cleared.

[image]

the new `client` on the `invoice` form still gets set correctly in the redux store, it just gets cleared from the Field's input value.  why?

- please note i am already manually calling input.onBlur() from the `Select` with the correct value, as per other answers.  i think this has something to do with creating a new option.

  // redux-form field wrapping the custom autocomplete component

  const clientOptions = clients.map(client => ({ label: client.email, value: client }))
  const isValidNewOption = ({ label }) => email.REG_EMAIL.test(label)
  const promptTextCreator = (label) => (`Send to ${label}`)
  const newOptionCreator = ({label, labelKey, valueKey}) => {
    return { label: label, value: { email: label } }
  }

// RFReactSelect, a react-select Creatable to act as an autocomplete with the ability to create a new option

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

RFReactSelect.defaultProps = {
  multi: false,
  className: ""
};

RFReactSelect.propTypes = {
  input: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,

    onBlur: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onFocus: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
  options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  multi: PropTypes.bool,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  onNewOptionClick: PropTypes.func,
};

export default function RFReactSelect(props) {
  const { input , options, multi, className,
    newOptionCreator, promptTextCreator, isValidNewOption } = props
  const { name, value, onBlur, onChange, onFocus } = input;
  const transformedValue = transformValue(value, options, multi);

  return (
    <Select.Creatable
      className={className}
      isValidNewOption={isValidNewOption}
      name={name}
      multi={multi}
      newOptionCreator={newOptionCreator}
      onSelectResetsInput={false}
      onBlurResetsInput={false}
      options={options}
      onChange={multi
        ? multiChangeHandler(onChange)
        : singleChangeHandler(onChange)
      }
      onBlur={() => onBlur(value)}
      onFocus={onFocus}
      promptTextCreator={promptTextCreator}
      value={transformedValue}
      valueKey='value'
    />
  );
}

/**
 * onChange from Redux Form Field has to be called explicity.
 */
function singleChangeHandler(func) {
  return function handleSingleChange(value) {
    func(value ? value.value : '');
  };
}

/**
 * onBlur from Redux Form Field has to be called explicity.
 */
function multiChangeHandler(func) {
  return function handleMultiHandler(values) {
    func(values.map(value => value.value));
  };
}

/**
 * For single select, Redux Form keeps the value as a string, while React Select
 * wants the value in the form { value: "grape", label: "Grape" }
 *
 * * For multi select, Redux Form keeps the value as array of strings, while React Select
 * wants the array of values in the form [{ value: "grape", label: "Grape" }]
 */
function transformValue(value, options, multi) {
  if (multi && typeof value === 'string') return [];

  const filteredOptions = options.filter(option => {
    return multi
      ? value.indexOf(option.value) !== -1
      : option.value === value;
  });

  return multi ? filteredOptions : filteredOptions[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

annnnd i solved it.  the issue was that you have to keep track of the newly created options in local state, and concat them with `props.options` of the component, otherwise the new ones are lost on re-render.  so the `value` passed back to the `onBlur` of the `Field` was null.  here's the source:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

class RFReactSelect extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      createdOptions: []
    }

    this.onNewOptionClick = this.onNewOptionClick.bind(this)
  }

  render() {
    const { input , options, multi, className,
      newOptionCreator, promptTextCreator, isValidNewOption } = this.props
    const { name, value, onBlur, onChange, onFocus } = input;
    const allOptions = options.concat(this.state.createdOptions)
    const transformedValue = this.transformValue(value, allOptions, multi);

    return (
      <Select.Creatable
        className={className}
        isValidNewOption={isValidNewOption}
        multi={multi}
        name={name}
        newOptionCreator={newOptionCreator}
        onSelectResetsInput={false}
        onBlurResetsInput={false}
        options={allOptions}
        onChange={multi
          ? this.multiChangeHandler(onChange)
          : this.singleChangeHandler(onChange)
        }
        onBlur={() => onBlur(value)}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onNewOptionClick={this.onNewOptionClick}
        promptTextCreator={promptTextCreator}
        ref='creatable'
        value={transformedValue}
        valueKey='value'
      />
    );
  }

  /**
   * Keep created options in local state or they will be lost
   * on re-render
   */
  onNewOptionClick(option) {
    const { props, select } = this.refs.creatable
    const { options } = props

    options.unshift(option)
    select.selectValue(option)

    this.setState({
      createdOptions: [option]
    })
  }

  /**
   * onChange from Redux Form Field has to be called explicity.
   */
  singleChangeHandler(func) {
    return function handleSingleChange(option) {
      func(option ? option.value : '');
    };
  }

  /**
   * onBlur from Redux Form Field has to be called explicity.
   */
  multiChangeHandler(func) {
    return function handleMultiHandler(values) {
      func(values.map(value => value.value));
    };
  }

  /**
   * For single select, Redux Form keeps the value as a string, while React Select
   * wants the value in the form { value: "grape", label: "Grape" }
   *
   * * For multi select, Redux Form keeps the value as array of strings, while React Select
   * wants the array of values in the form [{ value: "grape", label: "Grape" }]
   */
  transformValue(value, options, multi) {
    if (multi && typeof value === 'string') return [];

    const filteredOptions = options.filter(option => {
      return multi
        ? value.indexOf(option.value) !== -1
        : option.value === value;
    });

    return multi ? filteredOptions : filteredOptions[0];
  }
}

RFReactSelect.defaultProps = {
  multi: false,
  className: ""
};

RFReactSelect.propTypes = {
  input: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onBlur: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onFocus: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
  options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  multi: PropTypes.bool,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  onNewOptionClick: PropTypes.func,
}

export default RFReactSelect
```

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for this example?